# How to make pictures grow and shrink together in CSS with absolute position

Tags: html, css, image

If I have to use absolute position to keep the background picture and picture of the vector on the top of the page, but when I resize the window, even though the background picture shrinks, the vector stays in the same position. Is there a way to keep both at the top of the page and the vector to stay at the same relative position to the background image, and for them to grow and shrink together?
[What they currently look like after shrinking](https://i.stack.imgur.com/th4kY.jpg) and [what I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/haalW.jpg)

CSS:

```
.landingImage {
    z-index: 0;
    background-size: fill;
    background-size: 100vw 100vh;
    top: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: grid;
    width: 100%vw;
    max-height: 944px;
}
    
.landingText {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 0;
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    text-align: left;
    align-items: left;
    margin-top: 200px;
    margin-left: 100px;
    top: 0;
}
        
.wrapper {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 0;
    margin-top: 500px;
    margin-left: 500px;
    top: 0;
}
        
.vector{
    
}
```

HTML:

```
<Image className={indexStyles.landingImage} src={orcas} />

<div className={indexStyles.wrapper}>
    <Image className={indexStyles.vector} src={vector} />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is my snippet the solution to your question? I wasn't completely sure if I understood it.

If I did: Create a container for your impression and vector and make sure to set the container to `position: relative;`. Then give the impression a width of 100%. Give the vector a `position: absolute;` and calculate how to position it in the middle and how what the distance should be from the bottom of the container.

```css
.landing{
  position: relative;
}

.impression{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px; /* auto or remove this */
  border: solid 1px black; /* remove this */
}

.vector{
  width: 5vw;
  height: 5vw; /* auto, remove or unit like this: if you want to scale it use same unit (vw) as width */
  border: solid 1px black; /* remove this */
  
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 10%;
  left: calc((100% - 5vw) / 2); 
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <button>example</button>
</nav>

<div class="landing">
 <img class="impression" src="orcas.jpg">
 <img class="vector" src="vector.svg">
</div>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
```

Comment: your example is exactly what I wanted, but idk why my vector is not on the image anymore: see here(https://ibb.co/ZgzDLV2) and here(https://ibb.co/1v6kK0g)

Comment: in the screenshots the images are both block-elements still in the same (normal)flow. 

If you look at my example. You'll see that I'v made a DIV that contains the two images. This DIV was given `position: relative;`

Then the first image, the orcas, was given a `width: 100%`.  
And the second image, the vector, was only given a `position: absolute` with values for the bottom and the left. If it still doensn't work try the inspector tool of your browser to check the styling. Is there something that overwrites these values?